# Каким образом исправить неработающее условие проверки на четность?

Tags: python

Доброго времени суток) Изучаю python самостоятельно и столкнулся в проблемкой в задаче(((

*Задача:*
Создайте любую переменную строку и поместите туда любой текст. Сделайте так, чтобы все
нечетные по порядку слева на право символы стали “_”, а все символы, местоположение
которых четное и которые равны “a” - стали “b”. Например, для фразы “Ham is tasty” => "_*b* _s_t_s_y"

Мой код :

```
    valuet = "Ham is tasty"
    for char in valuet:
        if char [1::2]:
            print("_",end='')
        elif char [::2] and char == "a":
            print("b",end='')    
        else:
            print(char,end='')
```

Не могу разобраться **почему не отрабатывает первое условие `if` на нечетность?**(((
И **что можно подправить, чтобы работало условие?**

Comment: 1) не понимаю задачу. H - нечетный, значит финальная фраза должна начинаться с _, а этого нет. Почему там b первым идет? 2) Что должно представлять char [1::2] с  точки зрения нечетности?

Comment: 1)Как по мне не верно указан пример, поэтому считаю H как первый элемент нечетный. 
2)насколько я понял с описания к уроку что char  это тип данных в котором храниться один символ переменной, и [1::2] мы указываем на то что это будут не четные символы в переменной.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Общая рекомендация: многие относятся к программированию, как к магии (типа: "произнес непонятную формулу (=переписал кусок непонятного кода), махнул палочкой (=нажал Enter), и какие-то силы все сделали"). Это путь в никуда. Разбирайтесь в каждом шаге, который вы включаете в код (как на этапе обучения, так и в дальнейшем).

В частности:

1. Мне сложно понять, по какой логике вы предположили, что применение среза к одному символу как-то поможет увидеть четность, потому объяснение будет коротким: применять срез к одному символу вообще  не имеет смысла.
   Рекомендация: перечитайте, что такое срезы.
   (Если бы вы применили срез [1::2] ко всей строке, то вы получили бы все четные буквы, но что бы вы с ними потом делали в этом примере - затрудняюсь сказать. Их же еще и на соответствие букве "a" проверять надо, а затем все равно перемешивать с "_").
2. Вот простой код с исправленным условием. Первая проверка - на четность (с учетом сдлвига на 1 из-за отсчета с 0) и на "a", если не сработает - на остальную четность, оставшийся случай - нечетный. С ответом из примера ответ не совпадет, но как вы написали - у вас ответ неверный (возможно, тут вы тоже что-то не так поняли).

```
valuet = "Ham is tasty"
for i in range(len(valuet)):
    if i % 2 != 0 and valuet[i] == "a":
        print("b", end='')
    elif i % 2 != 0:
         print(valuet[i],end='')
    else:
        print("_",end='')
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ) 
Хотелось уточнить для себя: 
начиная цикл мы объявляем в нем переменную "i" далее проводим ранжирование от  0 до 11 (хотя элементов у нас 12) и подсчет элементов в переменной с помощью len 
после проверка условий 1- если элемент четный и == а то выводим b  или если у нас элемент четный то выводим его значение, во всех других случаях выводи "_" 
я правильно понял?

Comment: В целом правильно, только замечу что термин "ранжирование" по-русски = сортировка, а мы же всего лишь запускаем цикл. И цикл у нас длится ровно столько, какой длины у нас массив (от 0 включительно до 11 включительно и будет 12 - в программировании, как правило, с 0 начинают отсчет, хоть в жизни и с 1).

Answer (score 1):

В ответе [@Сергей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/489515/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B9) есть логическая ошибка. Если запустить код, то вывод должен быть: `Ham is tasty` => `_b _s_t_s_y`, а так получается: `H_m_i_ _b_t_`. Это получается, потому что счет ведется с 0, а не с 1. Для удобства лучше использовать встроенную функцию [`enumerate(iterable, start=0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Пример использования:

```py
>>> seasons = ['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter']
>>> list(enumerate(seasons))
[(0, 'Spring'), (1, 'Summer'), (2, 'Fall'), (3, 'Winter')]
>>> list(enumerate(seasons, start=1))
[(1, 'Spring'), (2, 'Summer'), (3, 'Fall'), (4, 'Winter')]
```

Решением будет:

```py
>>> valuet = 'Ham is tasty'
>>> for index, char in enumerate(valuet, start=1):
...     if index % 2 == 0 and char == 'a':
...             print('b', end='')
...     elif index % 2 == 0:
...             print(char, end='')
...     else:
...             print('_', end='')
... 
_b_ _s_t_s_y
```

Однострочный вариант:

```py
>>> valuet = 'Ham is tasty'
>>> new_valuet = ''.join(char if index % 2 else '_' for index, char in enumerate(valuet.replace('a', 'b')))
>>> new_valuet
'_b_ _s_t_s_y'
```

Comment: Да, исправил, спасибо. Так как автор не дал изначально рабочий тестовый пример (исправил позже), то и не проверял ночью. Фокус на другое был - не принципиально. Про `enumerate` - интересно. Впрочем, все равно придется проверять, то ли равенство выбрано.